# Ansible changes variable values when set

Tags: string, parsing, ansible

I have a series of variables set.   Call them Hosts and Inthosts.  Each has an appropriate value set, as seen in the debug output.  When I try to assign the value of inthosts to hosts, it does not actually make them the same, it bolloxes it up changing the double quotes to single quotes and putting a "u" in front  of each "item".  It there a way to force Ansible to actually do a literal equals in this case without parsing the text? The text should just be treated as a string. In this case the "modified" value is being output to a file, and the change breaks things.
  The plan was to use the default hosts,  and override it with inthosts if the server in question should be using a different set of servers.

**Default Variables Set**

```
filebeat_kafka_hosts: '["x.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093", "y.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093"]'

filebeat_kafka_inthosts: '["x.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093", "y.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093", "z.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093"]'
```

**Ansible Code**

```
- debug:
    msg: "Hosts {{ filebeat_kafka_hosts }} "

- debug:
    msg: "IntHosts {{ filebeat_kafka_inthosts }} "

- set_fact:
    filebeat_kafka_hosts="{{ filebeat_kafka_inthosts  }}"

- debug:
    msg: "Inthosts -> hosts {{ filebeat_kafka_hosts }} "
```

**Output (edited)**

```
"msg": "Hosts [\"x.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093\", \"y.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093\"] "                                                                                                                                               |

"msg": "IntHosts [\"x.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093\", \"y.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093\", \"z.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093\"] "

set  {"ansible_facts": {"filebeat_kafka_hosts": ["x.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093", "y.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093", "z.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093"]}, "changed": false}

"msg": "Inthosts -> hosts [u'x.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093', u'y.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093', u'z.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093'] "
```

Answer (score 0):

Ansible is interpreting `filebeat_kafka_inthosts` and `filebeat_kafka_hosts` as lists.  That gives you the 'u' characters before each item in your debug.  The tasks below

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ filebeat_kafka_hosts }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ filebeat_kafka_inthosts }}"
```

Would give you

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=y.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093) => {
    "item": "y.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093", 
    "msg": "y.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093"
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=x.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093) => {
    "item": "x.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093", 
    "msg": "x.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=x.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093) => {
    "item": "x.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093", 
    "msg": "x.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093"
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=y.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093) => {
    "item": "y.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093", 
    "msg": "y.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093"
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=z.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093) => {
    "item": "z.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093", 
    "msg": "z.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093"
}
```

Since your writing this line to a file, you shouldn't have to worry about it too much.  The 'u' character is a side effect of the debug module.  Writing the variable to a file would give the same result (although with single quotes instead of double).

```
- lineinfile:
    path: some_file
    line: "{{ filebeat_kafka_hosts }}"
```

**some_file**

```
['x.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093', 'y.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093', 'z.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093']
```

If you really need double quotes, you can use the `to_json` filter

```
- lineinfile:
    path: some_file
    line: "{{ filebeat_kafka_hosts | to_json }}"
```

**some_file**

```
["x.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093", "y.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093", "z.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9093"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that casting the variable as a string also works.  Thanks for the advice!